# How to pull int value from text file of strings and ints?

Tags: java, file, stack, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to write a program that is practically a stack. Given a text file with certain keywords, I want my program to evaluate the text line by line and perform the requested action to the stack.

For example, if the input file is:

```
push 10 

push 20

push 30
```

The resulting stack should look like:

```
30

20

10
```

However, I don't know how to push these values into the stack without hardcoding an int value after the word `push`. I made a String variable and assigned it to `scanner.nextLine()`

From there, I compare the line with strLine: if strLine is equal to `push` followed by some Number, then that number would be pushed on the stack.

However, it seems that the method `nextInt()` isn't taking this number from the input stream.

```
 Scanner input = new Scanner(file)
 int number;
 String strLine;
          while (input.hasNextLine()){
             strLine = input.nextLine();

          number = input.nextInt();
          if(strLine.equals("push " + number)){ 
              stack.push(number);
           }
```

How can I fix this? 
Thank you.

Comment: This is not your complete code, where is your `stack` object initiasation

Comment: `input.nextLine` reads the whole line, including the number.  What you can do instead is to use `input.next()` to get the "push" and `input.nextInt()` to get the number.

Comment: Thank you David, that worked!

Answer (score 1):

Get the input and split it with space " "!
That will give ["push","1"]
convert the first index to int and then push the value to stack!

```
  while (input.hasNextLine()){
          String[] strLine = input.nextLine().split(" ");
          if(strLine[0].equals("push")){
              stack.push(Integer.parseInt(strLine[1]));
          }
          else if(strLine[0].equals("pop")){
              stack.pop();
          }
          else{
              system.out.println("Please enter a valid input!");
           }
  }
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: `if(strLine[0]=="push"){` OH Really ?

Comment: yeah I get it. it should be equals! I've made the edit!

Comment: Not at all! I just missed the thanks in that comment .. :)

Comment: BTW, I personally like the split solution, made an edit for you

Comment: Indeed, the right approach if the input is structured is to utilize that structure.  Presumably the OP also will have pop or other operations to do as well.  Evaluating tokens[0] (as named in my answer) is where these operations will be stored.

Answer (score 1):

`input.nextLine` reads the whole line, including the number. What you can do instead is to use `input.next()` to get the "push" and `input.nextInt()` to get the number.  This example is using Scanner with System.in (so it needs "quit" to exit the while loop), but it should also work with a file (in which case you don't need to type "quit" to exit the program, as it will do so automatically when the input file has no more input). The advantage of using `parseInt` (as some of the other answers have suggested) is that you can catch any errors in integer input using a try/catch block.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;

public class StackScanner {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>();

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number;
        String strLine;
        while (input.hasNext()){
            strLine = input.next();

            if(strLine.equals("push")){
                try {

                    number = input.nextInt();
                    stack.push(number);
                } catch ( InputMismatchException e) {
                    System.out.println("Invalid input. Try again.");
                    input.nextLine();
                    continue;
                }
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(stack);
    }
}
```

Sample output:

```
push 5
push 6
push 3
quit
[5, 6, 3]
```

Comment: For some reason I'm able to push values like 2.5, 3.3, etc... How can I prevent this?

Comment: @Tyler I cannot reproduce your problem.  If I type in a value like 2.5 or 3.3, I get an InputMismatchException, which I can prevent by surrounding it in a try/catch block.

Comment: @Tyler I have edited my answer to include a try-catch block that will catch the `InputMismatchException`.

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
number = input.nextInt();
```

to this:

```
number = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem, I would simply tokenize the line by splitting on whitespace.

It looks like your input is relatively structured: you have a keyword of some kind then whitespace then a number.  If your data is indeed of this structure, split the line into two tokens.  Read the value from the second one.  For example:

```
String tokens[] = strLine.split(" ");
// tokens[0] is the keyword, tokens[1] is the value
if(tokens[0].equals("push")){
    // TODO: check here that tokens[1] is an int
    stack.push(Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]));
} else if (tokens[0].equals("pop")) { // maybe you also have pop
    int p = stack.pop();
} else if ... // maybe you have other operations
```

Comment: `if(tokens[0]=="push"){` OH Really ?

Comment: Also `split` does not take a `char`

Comment: Thanks!  Yes, obviously I rarely write Java.  Thanks for the improvements.  I hope that OP could see the point, which was that you ought to parse the line yourself since the input format structured.

Answer (score 0):

nextLine method parses the whole line including any numbers in the line. So, you need to take care of splitting the line and parsing the number in your code.

Something like below will work where I split the line with spaces. Although, there are many such ways possible.

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
    String strLine;
    Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<>();
    int number;
    while (input.hasNextLine()){
        strLine = input.nextLine();
        if(strLine.startsWith("push")){ 
            String[] sArr = strLine.split("\\s+");
            System.out.println(strLine);
            if(sArr.length==2){
                number=Integer.parseInt(sArr[1]);
                stack.push(number);
                System.out.println(number);
            }
        }
    }
```